# overlapping python stacked bar graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, overlap, z-order

Is there a way to set the zorder of each dataset in a multiple bar graph different at each x location so that all of the information is visible.

```
axes.bar(position,data_1,color='g')
axes.bar(position,data_2,color='r')
axes.bar(position,data_3,color='b')
```

for example, if a blue value is greater than a green value the green will be hidden behind and visa versa.  setting alpha to lower values than one creates more than 3 colors displayed from mixing of colors.

Comment: You probably need to check manually which bar is higher and run `bar()` twice with different zorders for one of the classes.

Comment: yeesh. that gets exponentially more complicated with more and more datasets to plot.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you iterate through the bins and sort them one by one, it shouldn't be too difficult. Usually this kind of plot is done by putting the bars next to each other, though.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to sort the bars individually at each bar location:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

L = 5

heights_a = 10. + np.random.randn(L)
heights_b = 10. + np.random.randn(L)
heights_c = 10. + np.random.randn(L)

position = np.arange(L)
colors = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2']

plt.figure()

for x, ha, hb, hc in zip(position, heights_a, heights_b, heights_c):
    for i, (h, c) in enumerate(sorted(zip([ha, hb, hc], colors))):
        plt.bar(x, h, color=c, zorder=-i)

plt.show()
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Ohh this is sweet. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck! `plot` has a `zorder` kwarg.

I tested it on `bar` just to be sure, using an example I have laying around.

```
summer = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Summer"].value_counts(), bar_width,
                label="Summer", zorder=2)

winter = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Winter"].value_counts(),
                bar_width, label="Winter", zorder=1)
```

Gives:

[image]

And if I reverse it:

```
summer = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Summer"].value_counts(), bar_width,
                label="Summer", zorder=1)

winter = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Winter"].value_counts(),
                bar_width, label="Winter", zorder=2)
```

[image]

Edit: I looked into the "bar within a bar" part of this, and, as noted in the comments elsewhere, it seems you would need to manually set the zorders based on a sorting of their values. You would probably want to modify the bar width based on that calculated zorder in order to get that visual effect.

Full code that I'm using as a reference example is given below for clarity:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = "Crime Type Summer|Crime Type Winter".split("|")
j = {x: [random.choice(["ASB", "Violence", "Theft", "Public Order", "Drugs"]) for j in range(300)] for x in s}
df = pd.DataFrame(j)

index = np.arange(5)
bar_width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
summer = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Summer"].value_counts(), bar_width,
                label="Summer", zorder=1)

winter = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Winter"].value_counts(),
                bar_width, label="Winter", zorder=2)

ax.set_xlabel('Category')
ax.set_ylabel('Incidence')
ax.set_title('Crime incidence by season, type')
ax.set_xticks(index)
ax.set_xticklabels(["ASB", "Violence", "Theft", "Public Order", "Drugs"])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: sorry i meant to say that the hiding behavior is undesired. I wish to be able to see both datasets no matter which one is larger.

Comment: So a bar within a bar basically? As opposed to putting the bars side by side

Comment: i think you understand what i am trying to accomplish. yes

Comment: Edited to respond to that, but I don't think you'll like it... is there a reason you can't use the side-by-side bar pattern? It seems much more straightforward to implement

Comment: side by side gets hard to read when there are many x positions